# Regular expression for finding suffixes of first occurrence of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create regular expression in Java to match first occurrence of some string (let's say A) together with all following occurrences of other string (let's say C) after the first one.

So for example:

```
XAXXAXXCXC
```

In this case, following matches should be produced:

```
AC (position 1 and 7)
AC (position 1 and 9)
```

I have partially succeeded with positive lookbehind (see below), but the problem is that it is not greedy, so A at position 4 is taken instead of the first one:

```
(?<=(A).{0,20})C
```

Comment: What are you accomplishing using this kind of match in terms of programming ? Or is this just for an experiment ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this by combination of possitive and negative lookbehind. But with a limitation, that the A must be before C to some defined length (in this case 20).

```
(?<=(?<!A.{0,20})(A).{0,20})C
```